# searchkick re indexing not working on rails application production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, searchkick

Im trying to use Searchkick in my application. However, I get

```
Searchkick::MissingIndexError 
Index missing - run Restaurant.reindex
```

I run `Restaurant.reindex` but it didn't solve the issue. I also tried the following: `rake searchkick:reindex:all` and I receive the Reindex complete message; however,I come up with the same missing index error when I submit the search query.

Do I need to deploy my rails application again on AWS?

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show me the output of Restaurant.first.search_data

Comment: {"id"=>1, "name"=>"The Fusion Kitchen", "address_id"=>1, "average_ratings"=>"4.5", "establishment_type"=>"Casual Dining", "cost"=>"950", "cuisine"=>"North Indian, Italian, Chinese, Mexican", "timing"=>"12:30 PM to 3:30 PM, 7:30 PM to 12 Midnight...", "extras"=>nil, "restaurant_menu_url"=>nil, "published"=>true, "featured"=>false, "slug"=>"the-fusion-kitchen-borivali-west", :address=>"Mumbai,Borivali West,Mumbai,Maharashtra,India,", :city=>"Mumbai", :location=>[19.254567, 72.848923], :phone_numbers=>["022 30151462"], :offers=>[], :cost=>950.0}

Comment: Have you tried your search query in rails console? like this Restaurant.search "term"

Comment: Yes. Its working there..